# What are the `unicode groups` and `block ranges` that can be specified in `\p{name}`?

Tags: regex, pcre, character-properties

What are the  `unicode groups` and `block ranges` that can be specified in character class `\p{name}`?

e.g.

```
\p{IsGreek}
```

Where Is the list of names & description available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) has lists.

You can also ask the [man pages](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) of PCRE itself:

> Sets of Unicode characters are defined as belonging to certain
>   scripts. A character from one of these sets can be matched using a
>   script  name. For example:
>
> ```
> \p{Greek}
> \P{Han}
> ```
>
> Those  that are not part of an identified script are lumped together
>   as "Common". The current list of scripts is:
>
> Arabic, Armenian, Avestan, Balinese, Bamum, Bengali, Bopomofo,
>   Braille, Buginese,  Buhid,  Canadian_Aboriginal, Carian, Cham,
>   Cherokee, Common, Coptic,  Cuneiform,  Cypriot,  Cyrillic,  Deseret, 
>   Devanagari,   Egyptian_Hieroglyphs,   Ethiopic,   Georgian, 
>   Glagolitic,  Gothic,  Greek, Gujarati, Gurmukhi,  Han,  Hangul, 
>   Hanunoo,  Hebrew,  Hiragana,  Imperial_Aramaic, Inherited,
>   Inscriptional_Pahlavi, Inscriptional_Parthian, Javanese, Kaithi,
>   Kannada, Katakana, Kayah_Li, Kharoshthi, Khmer,  Lao, Latin,  Lepcha, 
>   Limbu,  Linear_B,  Lisu,  Lycian,  Lydian,  Malayalam, Meetei_Mayek,
>   Mongolian, Myanmar, New_Tai_Lue, Nko, Ogham,  Old_Italic, Old_Persian,
>   Old_South_Arabian,  Old_Turkic, Ol_Chiki, Oriya, Osmanya, Phags_Pa,
>   Phoenician, Rejang, Runic,  Samaritan,  Saurashtra,  Shavian, Sinhala,
>   Sundanese,  Syloti_Nagri,  Syriac, Tagalog, Tagbanwa, Tai_Le,
>   Tai_Tham, Tai_Viet, Tamil, Telugu,  Thaana,  Thai,  Tibetan, 
>   Tifinagh, Ugaritic, Vai, Yi.

Comment: I actually found the same link just now :). Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the `man page` hadn't spotted the `Unicode character properties` section.

Comment: Unfortunately that list is wrong. `Adlam` to `Zanabazar_Square` is missing.

Comment: @Akiva: Perhaps you should take that up with PCRE lagging behind with Unicode support (or not updating their documentation).

Comment: @Joey Ive been searching for a discovery method that is not human error prone. Even something such as https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax gave me some false positives with `QRegularExpression`, not to mention `regex101`. I would imagine the ideal way would be to dump source files for the various implementations concerned, because it is going to vary greatly between languages/engines out there.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a list of the **Unicode Character Properties** that you can specify in the brackets: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Categories

Or you can match **Unicode Blocks** or **Scripts**, you can find information about that here:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#block and http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#script.